# Required to refresh page in order to logout

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a navbar component that I'm using on all my pages, but there is an issue with the logout function. The logout function only works when I refresh the page. How can I fix this problem? Thanks in advance!

```
const Navbar = ({setAuth}) => {

  const logout = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      localStorage.clear();
      localStorage.removeItem("token");
      setAuth(false);
      toast.error("Logout successfully");
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
    }
  };

  const userLink = (
  <>
    <li><Link className = "link" to="./Register" >Register </Link></li>
    <li><Link className = "link" to="./Login" >Login </Link></li>
  </>
 );
 const loginLink =(
 <>
      <li><Link className = "link" to="/dashboard">Dashboard</Link></li>
      <li><Link className = "link" onClick={logout} to="/">Logout</Link></li>
 </>
 )
    return(
     <Fragment>
    <nav>
        <ul className = {renderClassses()}>
            <li><Link className = "link" to="/">Home </Link></li>
            <li><Link className = "link" to="./About">About</Link></li>
            <li><Link className = "link" to="./Contact">Contact </Link></li>
            {!localStorage.getItem('token') ? userLink : loginLink}
        </ul>

        <div onClick= {handleNavLinksToggle} className="hamburger-toggle">
            <i className="fas fa-bars fa-lg"></i>
        </div>
       
    </nav> 
    </Fragment>
    
 )   
}
export default Navbar;
```

{setAuth} function is located in my App.js. used for verifying users for my login.

```
function App() {
  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);
  const setAuth = (boolean) => {
    setIsAuthenticated(boolean);
  };
  toast.configure();
  const checkAuthenticated = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/authentication/verify", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { jwt_token: localStorage.token },
      });
      const parseRes = await res.json();
      parseRes === true ? setIsAuthenticated(true) : setIsAuthenticated(false);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
    }
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    checkAuthenticated();
    if (localStorage.getItem("token")) {
      setIsAuthenticated(true);
    }
  }, []);
```

Also noticed when I click logout in my navbar this error appears

[image]

Comment: What is `setAuth` prop passed from? Is this issue that the navbar doesn't rerender to display the `userLink` links? Can you share the parent component code that (*presumably*) has the `setAuth` function?

Comment: @Drew Reese, I added the setAuth, but seems like Stackoverflow is limiting my code :(, cant add the rest.

Comment: One thing you can do is use `window.location.reload()` after `setAuth(false)` in logout method.

Comment: @MohammadAbdulAlim I've tried that before, it still doesn't refresh upon logout click.

Comment: can you please try with removing `e.preventDefault();` ?

Comment: @MohammadAbdulAlim Just tried, still doesn't refresh sadly.

Comment: Remove `async` from your logout method. There is nothing asynchronus task going on inside it.

Comment: Are you able to update your question now to include more of the `App` component and how it renders `Navbar` and passes props to it?

Comment: @Drew Reese no, requires me to add more text to match code, but I posted an image of the error I am getting

Comment: Odd, you haven't posted *that much* code. Are you passing `setAuth` to `Navbar`? Can you try to create a *running* codesandbox that reproduces the issue that we could inspect and live debug in?

Comment: @Drew Reese, yep I am passing set Auth to navbar.  I just added more code, the other code is just Router, switches, and routes. Also trying to do the codesandbox but there's so much errors lol